# I.E. kept crashing under excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

first time asking questions, so pardon for me if i missed anything obvious. Searched high and low but couldn't find a fix for my problem...

After running the code below for like 15 rows, the IE crashes with an error of this :
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeQ2I.png)

I tried slowing down the script as you can see below multiple times, tried changing to InternetExplorerMedium but still it runs into this problem.
I haven't tried changing to xmlHttp way of calling internet explorer, just because i don't really want to re-write everything above.

The purpose of this code is to scrape facebook's review ratings (slowly).
Thanks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Import Review
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
'Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
benchmarkRating = 4.245 'review benchmark

lastData = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For reviewHandle = lastData + 1 To lastRow

    Dim brand As String: brand = ActiveSheet.Cells(reviewHandle, 2)
    Dim homepage As String: homepage = "https://www.facebook.com/pg/"
    With appIE
        .navigate homepage & brand & "/reviews/"
        .Visible = False
        'For i = 0 To 4
        '   DoEvents
          ' Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        'Next i
    End With

    Do While appIE.Busy
       DoEvents
    Loop

    'Do Calculations.....

    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:" & Int((6 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)))
Next reviewHandle


ActiveSheet.Cells(reviewHandle, 2) = "Report executed on " & Now

appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = "Extract Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: ***Welcome to Stack Overlow!!* How to scrape web pages?"** is one of the most common Excel/VBA questions on this site (close to 1000 questions & answers) and elsewhere. I find it hard to believe that you've exhausted all options ([starting here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scrape+excel) before posting. Please see the [help/on-topic] and also "[ask]" and [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/) and also: [mcve]. If you run into a problem not covered elsewhere, [edit] your post.*Good Luck*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i posted this out of a last resort, as you mentioned, there is close to 1000 questions above scraping websites, but very little addresses the crashes behind it, and those that addresses it, i've tried them. But advise taken, i've cut down unncessary codes and left only the bare bones of code needed to scrape, but still sees crashes from I.E.